# VBA doesn't paste value

Tags: vba, excel

I have copied some data from a file and now I want to paste this to a file which already has some data with the help of VBA. I want the copied data below the previous data. But it doesn't paste the copied data range.

How should I approach for this?

Here's my code:

```
   Sub NewWorkshet()
'
' NewWorkshet Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t

Dim MyFile As String

MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Workbooks.Open (MyFile)

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$3339").AutoFilter Field:=2, 

Criteria1:="318"

   Range("A2").Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Selection.Copy

Windows("CodeCopy.xlsx").Activate

Dim sName As String

Dim sFound As Boolean

sName = InputBox(prompt:="Enter sheet name to find in workbook:", Title:="Sheet search")

If sName = "" Then Exit Sub
sFound = False

On Error Resume Next

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sName).Select


' Remove Filter

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$6274").AutoFilter Field:=17

Range("B2").Select

Selection.End(xlDown).Select

Selection.Offset(1, -1).Select

varTemp = ActiveCell.Address

ActiveSheet.Range(varTemp).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: In order to `Paste` you need to `Copy` first, where is your `Copy` ?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this would be pasting your data at the very end of your workbook (unless you have data below B2, in which case it would paste it there).

Comment: @ShaiRado I have already copied the data. I just have a problem in this paste section.

Comment: @BrandonBarney I have data from B1 to B1886 cell and I want to start the paste from A1887 but this code doesn't do this

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use (without using all the unnecessary `Select`) in case column B has data in all cells (no cells are left blank).

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, -1).PasteSpecial
```

In case you want to paste after the last row with data in column B, and there are some blank cells in the middle, you better of using:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).PasteSpecial
```

**Note**: it's better if you don't rely on `ActiveSheet`, instead use fully qualified object, such as `Worksheets("YourSheetName")`.

Comment: It's still not working. This selects the starting cell(B1886)but after that doesn't copy values.

Comment: @NILESHSUTHAR your post mentions issues with the `Paste` part, you said your `Copy` is OK. Please post all of your relevant code, so it will be easier to find where the error is coming from